# check and change each cell in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with indices and columns like ['a', 'b', 'c'] so it looks like this right now:

```
  a b c
a 0 0 0
b 0 0 0
c 0 0 0
etc
```

and then I have another dataframe that has ordered pairs and then a value like:

```
 pair   val
(a, b)  0.9
(b, c)  12
etc
```

is it possible to iterate or create a function that for cell in row a and col b can be assigned the value from the other dataframe with that specific pair? basically so that in row a and col b in the first dataframe, instead of 0 it would be 0.9?

I know I shouldn't iterate through dataframes, but I'm not sure how I can use apply() in this case

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do it with `update` and `unstack` after convert the pair to multiple index

```
another.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(another.pair)
df.update(another.val.unstack())
df
   a    b     c
a  0  0.9   0.0
b  0  0.0  12.0
c  0  0.0   0.0
```